# Need a precise explanation for this thymeleaf fragment signature

Tags: thymeleaf

I was doing a quick review of thymeleaf and I saw this UI code snippet:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout (~{::body},'home')}">
```

After some research [https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures], I have a general idea but this part of the code I am not sure what it means:

```
~{::body},'home')
```

So I need a really clear explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to break down the structure into a hierarchy by using what thymeleaf is using as fragment selectors (One of the features of Thymeleaf Fragments is that we can grab any part of a template just using the simple selectors, through classes, ids, or simply by tags).

```
"~{fragments/layout :: layout (~{::body},'home')}"
```

1. fragments/layout -> Selects the **layout.html** file under **fragments directory**.
2. :: layout -> Selects the **layout** markup fragment which is parametrized with two parameters.
3. (~{::body},'home') -> Passes two parameters to layout markup fragment. The first one is also a markup fragment selected with `::body`, the second one is basically a string valued `home`.

You can understand this with an example provided [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html) in which you can find under section 5.

Comment: Thanks for the link as well